# How can I load a bitmap inside my window?

Tags: winapi, bitmap

I'm trying to load a bitmap to a window I created. The bitmap should be the background of the window (I want to add labels on it an a progress bar later on).

This is my code:

```
HINSTANCE hInst;
LRESULT CALLBACK WindProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
WNDCLASSEX  WndCls;
static WCHAR szAppName[] = L"BitmapIntro";
MSG         Msg;

hInst = hInstance;
WndCls.cbSize = sizeof(WndCls);
WndCls.style = CS_OWNDC | CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
WndCls.lpfnWndProc = WindProcedure;
WndCls.cbClsExtra = 0;
WndCls.cbWndExtra = 0;
WndCls.hInstance = hInst;
WndCls.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
WndCls.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
WndCls.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
WndCls.lpszMenuName = NULL;
WndCls.lpszClassName = szAppName;
WndCls.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, IDI_APPLICATION);
RegisterClassEx(&WndCls);

CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
    szAppName,
    L"Bitmaps Fundamentals",
    WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    hInstance,
    NULL);

while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&Msg);
    DispatchMessage(&Msg);
}

return static_cast<int>(Msg.wParam);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
HDC hDC, MemDCExercising;
PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
HBITMAP bmpExercising;

switch (Msg)
{
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(WM_QUIT);
    break;
case WM_PAINT:

    hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);

    // Load the bitmap from the resource
    bmpExercising = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3));
    // Create a memory device compatible with the above DC variable
    MemDCExercising = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);
    // Select the new bitmap
    SelectObject(MemDCExercising, bmpExercising);

    // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
    BitBlt(hDC, 10, 10, 450, 400, MemDCExercising, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    // Restore the old bitmap
    DeleteDC(MemDCExercising);
    DeleteObject(bmpExercising);
    EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
    break;
default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
}
return 0;
}
```

The problem is, the PNG size is small compared to the window, so when the PNG opens, it only occupies the left high corner. How can I make it stretch to my window size or at least draw it over and over until it fills the window?

Comment: [StretchBlt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145120.aspx). Including all the ugly artifacts and quality degradation.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make it stretch to my window size

Use [`StretchBlt()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145120.aspx) instead of `BitBlt()`.

```
case WM_PAINT:
{    
    // Get the window dimensions
    RECT r;
    GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);

    // Load the bitmap from the resource
    HBITMAP bmpExercising = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3));

    // Get the bitmap dimensions
    BITMAP bmp;
    GetObject(bmpExercising, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

    PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
    HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);

    // Create a memory device compatible with the above DC variable
    HDC MemDCExercising = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

    // Select the new bitmap
    HBITMAP hOldBmp = SelectObject(MemDCExercising, bmpExercising);

    // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
    StretchBlt(hDC, 0, 0, r.right - r.left, r.bottom - r.top, MemDCExercising, 0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, SRCCOPY);

    // Restore the old bitmap
    SelectObject(MemDCExercising, hOldBmp);

    // Destroy the memory device
    DeleteDC(MemDCExercising);

    // Destroy the bitmap
    DeleteObject(bmpExercising);

    EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
    break;
}
```

> or at least draw it over and over until it fills the window?

There are two different ways to handle that.

1. at startup, load the bitmap and create an `HBRUSH` around it using [`CreatePatternBrush()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183508.aspx), and then assign that to the `WNDCLASS::hbrBackground` field when you register your window class.  Let the OS draw the window background using the bitmap for you.

   ```
   HBITMAP bmpExercising = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3));
   WndCls.hbrBackground = CreatePatternBrush(bmpExercising);
   ```
2. if you want to paint the bitmap manually, have your paint handler call `BitBlt()` in a couple of loops.  You know the dimensions of the bitmap (which you can retrieve in code using [`GetObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904.aspx) and the [`BITMAP`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183371.aspx) structure), and you know the dimensions of the window (which you can retrieve in code using [`GetWindowRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx) or [`GetClientRect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633503.aspx)).  So simply draw the same bitmap more than one time at different offsets as needed.  Start by drawing it once in the top-left corner, then move right bitmap-width pixels and draw it again, repeating until you move past window-width pixels.  Then move left back to 0 and move down bitmap-height pixels and repeat the whole width-line again, repeating until you move past window-height pixels.

   ```
   case WM_PAINT:
   {    
       // Get the window dimensions
       RECT r;
       GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);

       // Load the bitmap from the resource
       HBITMAP bmpExercising = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3));

       // Get the bitmap dimensions
       BITMAP bmp;
       GetObject(bmpExercising, sizeof(BITMAP), &bmp);

       PAINTSTRUCT Ps;
       HDC hDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &Ps);

       // Create a memory device compatible with the above DC variable
       HDC MemDCExercising = CreateCompatibleDC(hDC);

       // Select the new bitmap
       HBITMAP hOldBmp = SelectObject(MemDCExercising, bmpExercising);

       int width = r.right - r.left;
       int height = r.bottom - r.top;

       // Copy the bits from the memory DC into the current dc
       for(int y = 0; y < height; y += bmp.bmHeight)
       {
           for(int x = 0; x < width; x += bmp.bmWidth)
           {
               BitBlt(hDC, x, y, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, MemDCExercising, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
           }
       }

       // Restore the old bitmap
       SelectObject(MemDCExercising, hOldBmp);

       // Destroy the memory device
       DeleteDC(MemDCExercising);

       // Destroy the bitmap
       DeleteObject(bmpExercising);

       EndPaint(hWnd, &Ps);
       break;
   }
   ```

Now, with that said, here are some additional notes:

1. you should not be loading the bitmap inside of your paint handler.  Load it one time before creating the window, and then reuse the same `HBITMAP` for each paint operation until the window is destroyed, then free the bitmap.
2. `LoadBitmap()` is deprecated, you should be using [`LoadImage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045.aspx) instead, eg:

   ```
   HBITMAP bmpExercising = (HBITMAP) LoadImage(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP3), IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION);
   ```
3. you said "The bitmap should be the background of the window", so you should be drawing the bitmap in response to the [`WM_ERASEBKGND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055.aspx) message instead of the `WM_PAINT` message.

   ```
   case WM_ERASEBKGND:
   {    
       HDC hDC = (HDC) wParam;

       // draw the bitmap on hDC as needed...

       return 1;
   }
   ```