# How can I display a bitmap (array with color values) in a window using Window API?

Tags: c++, winapi, drawing

I want move a buffer of color values to a window using `BitBlt`, only the window shows up empty. When I compile and run the code from [How can I load a bitmap inside my window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37999289/how-can-i-load-a-bitmap-inside-my-window) (with my own example .bmp file), the window also shows up empty.

After some testing, the problem appears to be with `SelectObject()`. According to the documentation, when the return value is NULL an error has occered: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject. The return value is NULL, but `GetLastError()` gives 0, indicating there has not been an error. What is the problem here?

```cpp
    case WM_CREATE:
        std::fill(arr, arr + sizeof(arr), RGB(255,0,0));
        hBitmap = CreateBitmap(240, 120, 1, sizeof(COLORREF), (void*) arr);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        BITMAP bitmap;
        HGDIOBJ oldBitmap;
        HDC hdcMem;
        HDC hdc;

        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

        hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        oldBitmap = SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);
        std::cout << (oldBitmap == NULL) << std::endl;
        std::cout << GetLastError();

        GetObject(hBitmap, sizeof(bitmap), &bitmap);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bitmap.bmWidth, bitmap.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        SelectObject(hdcMem, oldBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hdcMem);

        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        break;
```

(BTW: I use `main()` instead of `WinMain()` and `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` each time I need the `hInstance`. As the window functions fine, I suspect it has nothing to do with this, but I'll mention it anyway.)

---SOLVED!---

I've got it working now :) For others seeing this, this is what I've changed:

```cpp
    case WM_CREATE:
        std::fill(arr, arr + 240 * 120, RGB(255,0,0));
        hBitmap = CreateBitmap(240, 120, 1, sizeof(COLORREF) * 8, (void*) arr);
        UpdateWindow(hwnd);
        break;
```

Comment: What is the color of that empty window?

Comment: White, the same as when I had an empty window.

Comment: `std::fill(arr, arr + sizeof(arr), RGB(255,0,0));` can not be correct, `sizeof(COLORREF)` is not valid as well because it is supposed to be bit depth

Comment: `SelectObject()` returns the object being replaced, which may be null. And GDI does not use `GetLastError()` to report errors. So there is no way to differentiate between a null object being returned and an actual error. Though, about the only error that could happen is if you were passing in an invalid `HDC` to select into. You are not checking the return values of `BeginPaint()` or `CreateCompatibleDC()` for errors

Comment: Thank you, I'm new with the Windows API so I did not know that :) (BTW: the `sizeof(arr)` mistake was just stupid of me, I've worked plenty of times with `sizeof()` and `fill()` before.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `arr` is a pointer, use the total number of elements (`240 * 120`)

If `arr` is an array, `sizeof` will return the total size in bytes. Instead use `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)` to find the count of array (total number of array's elements, or total number of pixels). For example, assuming `arr`'s element is 32-bit, then you are looking at `240 * 120` pixels, where each pixel is 4 bytes or 32 bits.

`CreateBitmap`'s 4th parameter expects the size in bits, so it should be `sizeof(*arr) * 8` or just 32.

```
uint32_t arr[240 * 120];
std::fill(arr, arr + sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr), RGB(255, 0, 0));
//or std::fill(arr, arr + 240 * 120, RGB(255, 0, 0));
hBitmap = CreateBitmap(240, 120, 1, 32, (void*)arr);
```

Note that this will produce a blue bitmap, not red, because it is using BGR format instead of RGB.

It appears you already know how to use memory dc. You can create a bitmap with `CreateCompatibleBitmap`, then select that bitmap in to memory dc, and use the standard GDI functions such as [`FillRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-fillrect). This will avoid the pitfalls with counting the bits and bytes.

Comment: Thank you so much, I've got it working now :) The `sizeof(arr)` mistake was kind of stupid, I've worked with `fill()` and `sizeof()` plenty times before, but that `CreateBitmap()` works with bits instead of bytes I did not know and would never have expected :)

Answer (score 0):

C++ class bellow allows easily create bitmaps using `CreateBitmap` function.

##### Steps to create bitmap

1. Allocate `ColorU` pixel array of desired dimensions.
2. Create bitmap using `CreateBitmap` function.

##### Example

In example error checking is omitted for simplicity reasons.

```cpp
// pixel array dimensions
const int32_t width = 720, height = 480;

Graphics::ColorU *pixelArray = new Graphics::ColorU[width * height];
for (size_t i = 0; i < width * height; i++) {
    pixelArray[i].setColor(Graphics::ColorU::DarkBlue);
}

// assume "window" is valid window handle
RECT client = GetWindowRect(window, &rect);
// assume "windowDC" is valid window DC
HDC tempDC = CreateCompatibleDC(windowDC);
HBITMAP bitmap = CreateBitmap(width, height, 1, 32, pixelArray);
HGDIOBJ obj = SelectObject(tempDC, bitmap);
BitBlt(windowDC, 0, 0,
    client.right - client.left,
    client.bottom - client.top,
    tempDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(tempDC, obj);
DeleteDC(tempDC);
DeleteObject(bitmap);

delete[] pixelArray;
```

---

##### Color.h: (C++11 or above)

```cpp
#ifndef _COLOR_
#define _COLOR_

#include <stdint.h>

using Byte = uint8_t;
using Word = uint16_t;
using Dword = uint32_t;

using Float = float;
using Uint32 = uint32_t;

using ColorRef = Dword;

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(disable:4005)
#endif // _MSC_VER
#define RGB(r, g, b) (ColorRef)(((Byte)(r))|(((Word)((Byte)(g)))<<8)|(((Dword)((Byte)(b)))<<16))
#define GetRValue(rgb) (Byte)((Dword)(rgb))
#define GetGValue(rgb) (Byte)(((Word)((Dword)(rgb)))>>8)
#define GetBValue(rgb) (Byte)(((Dword)(rgb))>>16)
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning(default:4005)
#endif // _MSC_VER

namespace Graphics {
    
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    // Struct "ColorU"
    // - This Struct Stores Color In GDI Compatible Format
    // Color Format
    // - BBGGRRXX: [ blue:Byte, green:Byte, red:Byte, reserved:Byte ]
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------
    struct alignas(Byte) ColorU {
    public:
        
        enum KnownColor : ColorRef {
            
            White = RGB(191, 191, 191),
            Gray = RGB(89, 89, 89),
            
            BrightWhite = RGB(255, 255, 255),
            Black = RGB(0, 0, 0),
            
            Red = RGB(255, 0, 0),
            Green = RGB(0, 255, 0),
            Blue = RGB(0, 0, 255),
            
            LightRed = RGB(255, 128, 128),
            LightGreen = RGB(128, 255, 128),
            LightBlue = RGB(128, 128, 255),
            
            DarkRed = RGB(128, 0, 0),
            DarkGreen = RGB(0, 128, 0),
            DarkBlue = RGB(0, 0, 128),
            
            Aqua = RGB(0, 191, 255),
            Purple = RGB(191, 0, 255),
            Yellow = RGB(255, 191, 0),
            
            LightAqua = RGB(0, 255, 255),
            LightPurple = RGB(255, 0, 255),
            LightYellow = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            
        };
        
    public:

        Byte blue;
        Byte green;
        Byte red;

    private:

        Byte reserved;

    public:

        // ----------------------------------------
        // constructors
        
        ColorU() noexcept {
            blue = 0x00;
            green = 0x00;
            red = 0x00;
            reserved = 0x00;
        }
        
        ColorU(KnownColor knownColor) noexcept {
            blue = GetBValue(knownColor);
            green = GetGValue(knownColor);
            red = GetRValue(knownColor);
            reserved = 0x00;
        }
        
        explicit ColorU(Byte red, Byte green, Byte blue) noexcept {
            this->blue = blue;
            this->green = green;
            this->red = red;
            reserved = 0x00;
        }
        
        ColorU(ColorRef rgbColor) noexcept {
            blue = GetBValue(rgbColor);
            green = GetGValue(rgbColor);
            red = GetRValue(rgbColor);
            reserved = 0x00;
        }
        
        // input color component range: [0.0F, 1.0F]
        explicit ColorU(Float red, Float green, Float blue) noexcept {
            this->blue = blue <= 0.0F ? 0 : blue >= 1.0F ? 255 : (Byte)(blue * 255);
            this->green = green <= 0.0F ? 0 : green >= 1.0F ? 255 : (Byte)(green * 255);
            this->red = red <= 0.0F ? 0 : red >= 1.0F ? 255 : (Byte)(red * 255);
            reserved = 0x00;
        }
        
        // ----------------------------------------
        
        // copy constructor
        ColorU(const ColorU &other) noexcept = default;
        // copy assigment operator
        ColorU& operator=(const ColorU &other) noexcept = default;
        
        // ----------------------------------------
        // setters
        
        void setColor(KnownColor knownColor) noexcept {
            blue = GetBValue(knownColor);
            green = GetGValue(knownColor);
            red = GetRValue(knownColor);
        }
        
        void setColor(Byte red, Byte green, Byte blue) noexcept {
            this->blue = blue;
            this->green = green;
            this->red = red;
        }
        
        void setColor(ColorRef rgbColor) noexcept {
            blue = GetBValue(rgbColor);
            green = GetGValue(rgbColor);
            red = GetRValue(rgbColor);
        }
        
        // input color component range: [0.0F, 1.0F]
        void setColor(Float red, Float green, Float blue) noexcept {
            this->blue = blue <= 0.0F ? 0 : blue >= 1.0F ? 255 : (Byte)(blue * 255);
            this->green = green <= 0.0F ? 0 : green >= 1.0F ? 255 : (Byte)(green * 255);
            this->red = red <= 0.0F ? 0 : red >= 1.0F ? 255 : (Byte)(red * 255);
        }
        
        // ----------------------------------------
        // hashing
        
        Uint32 hash() const noexcept {

            Uint32 hash = 47837;

            const Byte *data = (const Byte *)(this);
            Byte slidingWindow = 0x00;

            for (Byte i = 0; i < sizeof(ColorU) - 1; i++) {
                slidingWindow <<= 4;
                slidingWindow |= (data[i] & 0xF0) >> 4;
                hash += slidingWindow * (i + 1);
                slidingWindow <<= 4;
                slidingWindow |= (data[i] & 0x0F);
                hash += slidingWindow * (i + 1);
            }

            hash |= (hash ^ 47837) << 16;

            return hash;

        }
        
        // ----------------------------------------
        
        bool equal(const ColorU &other) const noexcept {
            return (
                blue == other.blue &&
                green == other.green &&
                red == other.red
            );
        }
        
        bool operator==(const ColorU &other) const noexcept {
            return equal(other);
        }
        
        bool operator!=(const ColorU &other) const noexcept {
            return !equal(other);
        }
        
        // ----------------------------------------
        // conversion
        
        ColorRef data() const noexcept {
            return RGB(red, green, blue);
        }
        
        operator ColorRef() const noexcept {
            return data();
        }
        
        // ----------------------------------------
        
        // default destructor
        ~ColorU() noexcept = default;
        
    };

}

#endif // !_COLOR_
```